# How to have a single code base of an iOS app but load images, config settings, etc from a client specific bundle

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

Is there a way to include a client specific bundle in my iOS app? I want to keep my code base the same but for each client I sell my app to, I want to include a specific bundle. The bundle will contain things like images (app icon?), files and configuration settings. Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could held your code in git repositories. The main/shared code could be in one repo. which you would then include as submodule in the other per-client git repositories.
2. You could do a Build-Target for each client (depends on how many client you have. Make send from 2-10)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going to go with option 1